# R assign rolling value for all rows in column A if values are the same in columns B and C using loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a new column named Purchase ID with a rolling number from 1 to the end of the row if the data has the same "ID", "Date" and "Action=6".
Therefore, for rows with ID=P40, and Date = 26072013, and Action = 6, a new column with purchase ID 1 will be assigned to these rows. Next, for rows with ID=P42, and Date = 01072014, and Action = 6, the value in purchase ID column will keep rolling to 2. Here is the sample data. That would help a lot!! Thanks so much!!

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(list(ID = c("P40", "P40", "P40", "P40", "P42", "P42"),
                      Date = dmy(c(26072013, 26072013, 2092012, 23082012, 01072014, 01072014))),
                      Action = c("1", "6", "1", "1", "6", "1"))
```

This is the code I am trying to work on but obviously, it doesn't work out..

```
PurchaseID <- c()
for (row in df){
   if (length(unique(df$ID))==1 & length(unique(df$date))==1) {
      df %>% mutate(PurchaseID = seq(100,by = 1,length.out = nrow(df)))
   } else {
      PurchaseID <- c(PurchaseID, "NA")
   }
}}
```

UPDATE!!: Thanks for the comments and here is the desired output. I am working with 200K data so this is only an extract. I want to create a new column with rolling value that matches

1. action = 6,
2. same ID in the column,
3. same date in the column.

Hopefully, it sounds clearer! Great thanks!!!!

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(list(ID = c("P40", "P40", "P40", "P40", "P42", "P42"),
              Date = dmy(c(26072013, 26072013, 2092012, 23082012, 01072014, 01072014)),
              Action = c("1", "6", "1", "1", "6", "2"), 
              PurchaseID = c("NA", "001", "NA", "NA", "002", "NA") ))
```

Desired Ouput:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Firstly your're using probably `lubridate` in your code, better to point it out. Second, could you add the desired output given the example data you've put? It's going to be easier to help.

Comment: what do you expect as your final result? Include that in your question

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your reply! I am working with 200K data so I just extract part of it. Here is the desired output. 

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(list(ID = c("P40", "P40", "P40", "P40", "P42", "P42"),
                      Date = dmy(c(26072013, 26072013, 2092012, 23082012, 01072014, 01072014)),
                      Action = c("1", "6", "1", "1", "6", "2"), 
                      PurchaseID = c("NA", "001", "NA", "NA", "002", "NA") ))

Comment: Does `df %>% group_by(action) %>% mutate(PurchaseId = ifelse(Action == 6, row_number(), NA))` do it? It does not sound like something you originally described, but suits the expectations you provided

Comment: what you are talking about is not a rolling value; it's a running index, i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `data.table::rleid`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Action==6, PurchaseID:=rleid(ID,Date)][]
```

Output:

```
    ID       Date Action PurchaseID
1: P40 2013-07-26      1         NA
2: P40 2013-07-26      6          1
3: P40 2012-09-02      1         NA
4: P40 2012-08-23      1         NA
5: P42 2014-07-01      6          2
6: P42 2014-07-01      1         NA
```

alternatively/much slower (perhaps tidyverse wizards have a better way)

```
bind_rows(
  filter(df, Action!=6),
  filter(df, Action==6) %>% 
    mutate(PurchaseID=data.table::rleid(ID,Date))
) %>% arrange(ID,Date,Action)
```

Output:

```
   ID       Date Action PurchaseID
1 P40 2012-08-23      1         NA
2 P40 2012-09-02      1         NA
3 P40 2013-07-26      1         NA
4 P40 2013-07-26      6          1
5 P42 2014-07-01      1         NA
6 P42 2014-07-01      6          2
```

Comment: Hi~ thanks so so so so much!! Tried on my sample and master data that they both work!!! 
I go into the wrong direction for the "for" loop and I also don't know this function "data.table::rleid" but good I learn it today! :) 
Thanks all again and hv a nice day!!!